# Redshift add new column based on values from existing column

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a Redshift table I want to alter adding a new column, which values are derived from an existing column on the table.

Basically, only adding a column "year" which extracts the year from the column "snapshot_date".

Any ideas how to achieve that? Tried following code, but it errors out.

```
ALTER TABLE test_schema.table_name ADD year AS ( extract(year from snapshot_date) );
```